# Paperclip attachment is saved, then read, but not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, asynchronous, filesystems, paperclip

My application receives email, stores it into an Email model (email message as a paperclip attachment) and processes it. Sometimes it happens that during the processing time the email message is not available, yet. This far I haven't been able to reproduce the issue, but it happens on my production server every now and then.

I suspect that somewhere in the stack the saving of the file is handled asynchronously. But where.

The Email model is saved and processing started with

```
email = Email.new
email.yaml_message = StringIO.new(@message.to_yaml)
email.save!
Email.delay(:retry => false).process(email.id)
```

It is Sidekiq's delay extension that is used to move the processing into a new thread.

Then in the Email model I read the message with

```
def message
  begin
    Mail::Message.from_yaml(File.read(yaml_message.path))
  rescue
    nil
  end
end
```

During the email processing I call `message.from` and sometimes the message is `nil`. But when I go to the server and open the model in console the message is there. I cannot think anything but asynchronous file saving that could cause something like this.

So is it Paperclip that introduces asynchronous file saving or is it deeper in the stack?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that there were outdated Sidekiq processes running on the server. I should have only one Sidekiq process running but there were four of them. Other vice it would not be an issue but the oldest processes referred to a code that was already removed from the server.

Now I need to figure out how to handle Capistrano, Monit and long running Sidekiq processes when deploying a new version.